# Get total hit count with Postgres full text search

Tags: postgresql, search, full-text-search

When doing a Postgres full text search, is it possible to return the top 10 relevance-ranked rows (using LIMIT), but also get the total number of rows found?

I'd like to implement a Google-like message in my search results: "Showing rows 1 to 10 of 1000 results"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions for that:

```
SELECT
  *,
  COUNT(*) OVER ()
FROM table
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Wow. That really works. I wonder about performance? Any insight?

Comment: @ccleve the same as `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table`